# Comparando dois data frames em python

Tags: python, pandas

Boa tarde senhores.

Sou novato em python, e em programação. Estou tentando comparar dois data frames diferentes, cada um com os dados de carros de um ano específico. Por enquanto eu fiz o seguinte:

```
year_08 = np.repeat('2008', 1061) # Variável com a quantidade de linhas do dataframe de 2008
year_18 = np.repeat('2018', 832) # Variável com a quantidade de linhas do dataframe de 2018

df_08['year'] = year_08 # Criando uma nova coluna com o ano no dataframe de 2008
df_18['year'] = year_18 # Criando uma nova coluna com o ano no dataframe de 2018

df = df_08.append(df_18, ignore_index=True) # Juntando os dois dataframes
```

Também consegui ver o aumento que houve de um ano para outro com o seguinte:

```
fuel01 = df
fuel01 = fuel01[fuel01.fuel != 'Gasoline'] # Exclui as linhas que tem 'Gasoline' como dado
fuel01['year'].value_counts()
```

Só que não gostei da maneira que ficou, queria algo, digamos, mais profissional. Alguma ideia de como faze-lo?

Obrigado.

Comment: Você poderia explicar melhor os seus dados e como quer comparar eles? > Tentei usar o np.repeat mas não deu certo pois possuo valores que são strings (...) Se houver a possibilidade, você pode dar drop nos valores que são strings você faria algo como: df = df[not isinstance(df.coluna,str)]

Comment: Bom dia.

Então, estou comparando dois dataframes, um com informação de carros do ano de 2008 e outro com informações de carros de 2018. Nessa questão eu preciso comparar se houve aumento no uso de fontes alternativas de combustível de um ano para outro. Eu fiz o seguinte: criei uma variável com repeat com cada ano, depois adicionei uma coluna nos dataframes com o nome 'year' e depois uni os dois frames. Agora tenho um único dataframe que tem uma coluna que mostra de que ano que é aquele modelo de carro. Vou editar na minha pergunta para você entender melhor.